# How to convert audio from stereo to mono in Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-music-player

I use the android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI intent to load music files from the SD Card.

```
Intent tmpIntent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(tmpIntent1, 0);
```

and in onActivityResult

```
Uri mediaPath = Uri.parse(data.getData().toString());
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, mediaPath);
mp.start();
```

Now MediaPlayer plays the audio in stereo. Is there any way to convert the selected music/audio file or the output from stereo to mono in the app itself?

I looked up API for [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) and [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html), but didn't find how to convert mp3 files audio to mono.

Apps like PowerAMP have those Stereo <-> Mono switches that when pressed immediately convert the output audio to mono signal and back again, how do they do it?

Comment: Did you by any chance figure out a solution to this yet? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: @dg123 nope, couldn't find anything!

Answer (score 3):

Do you load .wav- files respectively PCM- data? If so then you could easily read each sample of each channel, superpose them and divide them by the amount of channels to get a mono signal.

If you store your stereo signal in form of interleaved signed shorts, the code to calculate the resulting mono signal might look like this:

```
    short[] stereoSamples;//get them from somewhere

    //output array, which will contain the mono signal
    short[] monoSamples= new short[stereoSamples.length/2];
    //length of the .wav-file header-> 44 bytes
    final int HEADER_LENGTH=22;

    //additional counter
    int k=0;


    for(int i=0; i< monoSamples.length;i++){
        //skip the header andsuperpose the samples of the left and right channel
        if(k>HEADER_LENGTH){
        monoSamples[i]= (short) ((stereoSamples[i*2]+ stereoSamples[(i*2)+1])/2);
        }
        k++;
    }
```

I hope, I was able to help you.

Best regards,
G_J

Comment: Files can be **any** audio file on user's device, mp3 too. Once the user selects the file, I get the absolute path to the mp3 file on the SD Card. How do I process the file now? I am using MediaPlayer API to play the file. What I'm building is kind-of a music player, so any suggestions for using any other API other than MediaPlayer are welcome.

Comment: As far as I know, does neither MediaPlayer nor SoundPool nor AudioTrack offer a method to change playback from stereo to mono. So I assume, that my answer above is the only way to achieve this. Correct me, if I'm wrong.
If the audiofiles can be mp3 as well, you have to transform them into PCM- data, calculate the mono signal and playback via AudioTrack.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, get an encoder to convert your audio file to short array (short[]).

Then convert the short array to mono by splitting the streams.

Then average the split streams.

```
short[] stereo  = new short[BUF_SIZE];
short[] monoCh1 = new short[BUF_SIZE/2];
short[] monoCh2 = new short[BUF_SIZE/2];
short[] monoAvg = new short[BUF_SIZE/2];

stereo = sampleBuffer.getBuffer(); //get the raw S16 PCM buffer here

 for( int i=0 ; i < stereo.length ; i+=2 )
 {
     monoCh1[i/2] = (short) stereo[i];
     monoCh2[i/2] = (short) stereo[i+1];
     monoAvg[i/2] = (short) ( ( stereo[i] + stereo[i+1] ) / 2 );
 }
```

**Now you have:**

PCM mono stream from channel 1 (Left channel) in `monoCh1`

PCM mono stream from channel 2 (Right channel) in `monoCh2`

PCM mono stream from averaging both channels in `monoAvg`